# CMake and C source hierarchy

Tags: c, cmake, directory-structure

I am used to the following structure in most of my projects:

```
src/
inc/
ext/
build/
[...]
CMakeLists.txt
README
LICENCE
```

Where `src` is the directory where my sourcecode is in, `inc` are the headers, `ext` is the place to put external libraries in (which are then built by CMake).

---

It does not look like this structure is a good one because I am facing the following problem:

1. I am writing a library.
2. In my `inc` directory **all** my headers are, **private** and **public** ones.
3. In my `CMakeLists.txt` I use something like the following:

   ```
   target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
       PUBLIC
           inc
   )
   ```

The problem is, that now **all** headers are propagated to the super-project, even the private ones. A possible solution would be to have a `private` and `public` folder inside `inc`, hence:

```
src/
inc/
  private/
  public/
ext/
build/
[...]
CMakeLists.txt
README
LICENCE
```

I could then use:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        inc/public
    PRIVATE
        inc/private
)
```

The question is if someone can think of any serious trade-offs? Maybe there is even a "suggested hierarchy" by CMake?

Comment: Store private headers inside `src` and use `#include "..."` for including them. Store public only headers inside `inc` and use `#include < ... >` for including them.

Comment: @KamilCuk definitely a solution that works, I will then add `src/` as a `PRIVATE` inside `target_include_directories(...)`, even if unnecessary.

Comment: I am going to delete this question since nobody upvoted it - and therefore I am not allowed to ask something anymore... I someone is against the deletion, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not a fan of CMake. I use GNU make, that comes bundles with my OS, and I'm both happy and my code requires less from collaborators.

But CMake aside, I would re-visit the structure.

Your folder structure, although not uncommon, says nothing about the library or its components. It doesn't provide a future maintainer with any usable information.

Consider the following source code structure:

```
src
src/io
src/http
src/pubsub
src/database
```

Suddenly, without reading a single line of code, I have a strong hint about what the application (or library) might be and where I can find each component I might need to review.

Look at the [Linux repo](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) for example.

In libraries, this is often more important, because (hopefully) many people will read the code and contribute.

So you may ask **where does the include folder go?**...

The issue with separating the header files from the source files is that it makes maintenance harder.

I recommend that the `usr/include` (public include files for installation) be created dynamically, using a script or using `make`... but since you're using CMake, consider specifying each public header, or:

Another common option, which assumes that the public headers are distinctly separate from the implementation headers (i.e., contain API restriction and aren't edited except during a major revision), is to place them in a separate `include` folder.